# systemd service does not last more than 6 hours

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl

I am getting this error message in my logs:

```
 Stopping User Manager for UID 1000
```

I think that's the reason why my systemd service does not keep running. Does anyone know what that means, and how I can keep my services running 24/7? The service definition looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Interos MongoDB+ES log capture
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=interos_emit_only_json=yes
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/env/es-service.env
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/repos/elastic-search-app/syslog-exec.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I think it's doing that because of a SIGTERM, when I close the terminal window. Seems really odd. Why would a service listen for SIGTERM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systems user services by default only run as long as there is at least one session active for the user. When a user logs out from the last (or only) session, the `systemd --user` instance for that user is killed. You can change this by enabling lingering of systemd user instances. This is done per user using the following command: `loginctl enable-linger *username*`.  When lingering is enabled, the user services are started at boot, and continue to run even if there is no active session for the user.

Comment: I hope this works, giving it a try thanks

Comment: Magic. I was missing sporadic attestations on my Ethereum 2.0 validator when the process of stopping systemd took the unit briefly off line at the top of every hour. When that occasionally coincided a narrow attestation window, I'd miss out. This appears to have fixed it.